# How to Run Cucumber and RSPEC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, rspec2

right now I use rspec for my tests. to run rspec all I have to do is:

rake spec

I now want to use Cucumber to write tests for making sure the paths for sign in and sign up work correctly with Devise & Omniauth.

To use Cucumber I need to write tests in /features right?

So does that mean to test I need to run

```
rake spec
```

And then run another command

```
cucumber
```

So now I have to run two testing frameworks?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. One is a unit testing framework, the other is for high level acceptance tests.

Also, if you are looking for integration tests rather then acceptance tests (which is what it sounds like), plain capybara with rspec will probably be a better fit (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara, scroll down to capybara + rspec)

Answer (score 10):

Adapted from http://blog.andywaite.com/2013/02/28/rakefile-cucumber-rspec-jasmine/

Rakefile:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new

task :default => [:spec, :cucumber]
```

But I prefer [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to automatically run tests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's correct. Generally speaking I use Rspec for unit testing, and cucumber for integration. If you find RSpec is covering integration tests for you, and you dont need to write cucumber features to spec out the app with a client or systems analyst, then perhaps cucumber is not for you. Personally, i love how cucumber works for integration testing. It feels very reusable, and it's easy to understand what's going on in a test.

Answer (score 1):

To address your specificity about running 2 commands, running autotest to automatically run your tests whenever you make a change to the spec code or program code removes the need to use the rake commands.

https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Autotest-Integration

If you use cucumber the running `AUTOFEATURE=true autotest` will run rspec tests and cucumber specs in sequence

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Autotest-Integration

Autotest has a great function in that it runs the whole spec suite but, if any tests fail it will rerun only that test until it passes, and then reruns the entire test again.  It also has the added value of randomizing the order of tests so that it ensures the tests are valid in isolation